# GTM OAuth does not download Refresh Token - iOS

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, access-token, gtm-oauth2

I am using Google's GTMOAuth for iOS/Mac SDK in order to be able to connect with APIS such as YouTube API and Instagram API. It all works fine, however when the user authenticates, I can only get access token. This is all well and good, but after a while the access tokens expire and the user has to re-login which is awful.

My problem is that when the user authenticates, I ONLY GET back an access token and nothing else...

Thanks for you're help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be this one help you..!

I am using Google oauth 2.0, for google drive authentication.

In the Google finished with authentication method save the accesstoken and refresh token values in NSUSerDefaults like this.

```
 - (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult

           error:(NSError *)error
    {

        if (error != nil)
        {

          [self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];

            self.driveService.authorizer = nil;

        }
        else
        {
            self.driveService.authorizer = authResult;

            self.auth = authResult;

            NSLog(@"\n accessToken value is %@",self.auth.accessToken);

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.auth.refreshToken forKey:@"refreshToken"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.auth.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];

            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


        }

    }
```

After that when ever you want to use the acces token for performing api call first make a call using existing accesstoken value from the NSUSERDefaults, after that in the url response check the status code. If you are getting status code '401' means your access token is expired, and not valid. Then you have to request for refresh token using saved refresh token value in NSUserDefaults like this.

This is your first api call to check accesstoken valid or not.

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
    {
        NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        //int responseStatusCode = [httpResponse statusCode];
        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
//Your api call success and accesstoken is valid.


        } else if(httpResponse.statusCode == 401 && connection == self.conn2) {

            [[self appDelegate] refreshAccessToken];
        } 
    }
```

This is for request new accesstoken from refresh token.

```
-(void)refreshAccessToken {


    NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&refresh_token=%@&grant_type=refresh_token",kClientID,kClientSecret,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"refreshToken"]];
    NSData *postData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
    NSLog(@"\n request str : %@",request);

    NSLog(@"\n refresh token value is %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"refreshToken"]);
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];//connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if(connection)
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }

    [connection start];


}
```

In response check for status code again and if status code is 200.Then update the value in userdafaults.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Response %@", response);
    //NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    self.data = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSLog(@"Did Receive Data %@", data);
    [self.data appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
    NSLog(@"Did Fail %@",error);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Did Finish");
    // Do something with responseData
    NSError *err;
    id JSon = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.data options:kNilOptions error:&err];
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"%@",err);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Json %@",JSon);
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"accessToken"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[JSon valueForKey:@"access_token"] forKey:@"accessToken"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    }
}
```

This is my first answer on stack overflow. Sorry for any mistakes.

**UPDATE BELOW - Written by Supertecnoboff**

Also keep this in mind. For some API's such as Google, you need to add "approval_prompt=force" and "access_type=offline" if you want it to give you a refresh token. In order to add these parameters, you have to edit the GTMOAuth2SignIn.m file and replace the "paramsDict" with this NSMutableDictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *paramsDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"code", @"response_type",
                                 clientID, @"client_id",
                                 scope, @"scope", // scope may be nil
                                 @"force", @"approval_prompt",
                                 @"offline", @"access_type",
                                 nil];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you're answer. It has really helped me in terms of understanding the logic. However I still have one problem left. Doing "self.auth.refreshToken" returns null.... Where as when I try to download the access token "self.auth.accessToken" it works. So why is it not downloading any refresh token????

Comment: I didn't get you. Could please explain me a little bit, so maybe I can help you.

Comment: So basically you know the method called "finishedWithAuth" you can get a copy of the accessToken and the refreshToken by doing the following: "self.auth.accessToken" and "self.auth.refreshToken". Well basically when I do "self.auth.accessToken" I can get a copy of the accessToken. But when I try to do "NSString *refresh = self.auth.refreshToken" I can't get the refresh token because the refresh token is null..... ?????

Comment: May be it is correct or not I don't know, actually you can get refresh token only when you logged into gmail account for the first time. Then you have to save the refresh token in user defaults.

Comment: Yeah I know that. But if you set approval_prompt=force you will get a refresh token on the authentication request. Even if the user has authorised you're app once before. The point is even when I reauthorise my app and then reauthorise, I still don't get a refresh token.. :(

Comment: Sorry about that one. I didn't work with approval_prompt=force.

Comment: Well may I ask what you worked with in order to get a refresh token?? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50845/discussion-between-koti-tummala-and-supertecnoboff)

Comment: I managed to figure it out :) And I am still going to tick your answer as it helps me understand how to use the refresh token :) Thank you for your time Koti :)

Comment: I am glad you are able to resolve your issue. May be you can edit my answer to your updated one, So it may help someone. Thank you.

Comment: Yep, I have added the edit. Please accept the edit so that it is publicly viewable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the **GTMOAuth2Authentication**´s `authorizeRequest:completionHandler:` method

If your application saves the authorization to the keychain (by setting the controller's keychainItemName), it can be retrieved the next time the application launches:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                                                          clientID:kClientID
                                                                                    clientSecret:kClientSecret];

NSLog(@"accessToken: %@", auth.accessToken); //If the token is expired, this will be nil
```

and then you can refresh the access token like this:

```
// authorizeRequest will refresh the token, even though the NSURLRequest passed is nil
[auth authorizeRequest:nil
             completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
                 }
                 else {
                     NSLog(@"accessToken: %@", auth.accessToken); //it shouldn´t be nil
                 }
             }];
```

The token will be then refreshed and you can keep making queries.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have one more question: Is that necessary to create credentials for WEB Key in google developer console for get the client_secret or I can find it in iOS app/.plist file?

Comment: As far as I remember, I think you needed to create some credentials in Google developer console. Not sure if web key or iOS Client key.
Besides you´ll need to store in your app/.plist some parameters (like ClientID and/or ClientSecret) in order to make google´s library work.

Comment: In credentials I only have clientID for iOS, so in the request client_secret might be nil?

Comment: Exactly.. At least is what they say in the [iOS Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios). They are using nil as SecretId.
Perhaps in my code we were using a Web Id, with clientSecret. But I don´t have access to that console anymore...

Comment: Oh God, what a secret knowledge! Thank you for your answer, it works perfectly and I didn't saw this solution in google's documentation and wherever on the internet