# How to get access token for Gmail api using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, oauth-2.0, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

The following code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

// Create a UITextView to display output.
self.output = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
self.output.editable = false;
self.output.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0);
self.output.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:self.output];

// Initialize the Gmail API service & load existing credentials from the keychain if available.
self.service = [[GTLServiceGmail alloc] init];
self.service.authorizer =
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:kKeychainItemName
                                                      clientID:kClientID
                                                  clientSecret:nil];

[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientID;
[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently];
NSLog(@"token: %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken);
}

- (void)viewController:(GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *)viewController
  finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)authResult
             error:(NSError *)error {
if (error != nil) {
    [self showAlert:@"Authentication Error" message:error.localizedDescription];
    self.service.authorizer = nil;
}
else {
    self.service.authorizer = authResult;
    NSLog(@"Token: %@ id: %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken, [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.userID);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

   }
}
```

Always gives me a ' token: (null) id: (null)' in logs when I try to output the access token and userID. However, authorization goes fine.
Could anybody tell me what's wrong, how to get the access token correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
NSLog(@"Token: %@ id: %@", [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.accessToken, [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.userID);
```

into this:

```
NSLog(@"Token: %@ id: %@", authResult.accessToken, authResult.userID);
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the http method using which I can refresh access token after this token expired?

Comment: May I use authResult.refreshToken for the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21934196/2640210. This answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alvis!